# Graphviz: Place edge label on the other side

Tags: graphviz, dot

This may be related to [How to place edge labels ON edge in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350617/how-to-place-edge-labels-on-edge-in-graphviz): I have the following graph, which I visualize using the command `dot -Teps g.dot > g.eps`:

```
graph triple {
    node [shape=box]; User; Object; Tag;
    node [shape=diamond,style=filled]; Triple;
    {
        User -- Triple [label = "1"];
        Object -- Triple [label = "1"];
    }
    {
        rank=same;
        User;
        Object;
    }
    Triple -- Tag [label="n"];
}
```

I would like the result to be more symmetric by putting the label between User and Triple on the left side of the graph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And here's the second workaround using `splines=false` and double edges:

```
graph {
splines=false;
node [shape=box]; User; Object; Tag;
node [shape=diamond,style=filled]; Triple;
    {
        User   -- Triple [label = "1"];
        User   -- Triple [label = ""];
        Object -- Triple [label = ""];
        Object -- Triple [label = "1"];
    }
    {
        rank=same;
        User;
        Object;
    }
    Triple -- Tag [label="n"];
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 29):

Manual placement of edge labels cannot be done with graphviz.

However, you could use the `headlabel`, `labeldistance` and `labelangle` attributes:

```
graph triple {
node [shape=box]; User; Object; Tag;
node [shape=diamond,style=filled]; Triple;
    {
        User   -- Triple [headlabel = "1", labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=20];
        Object -- Triple [headlabel = "1", labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-20];
    }
    {
        rank=same;
        User;
        Object;
    }
    Triple -- Tag [label="n"];
}
```

Output:

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: Why do you need  "rank same" in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to get it to work in Graphviz. Instead, I rendered as a pdf, marked up the pdf to add labels myself, and then flattened the pdf into a new pdf so the markups would be part of the pdf.