# graphviz - how to create labels over straight arrows

Tags: graphviz

Maybe I'm trying to bend graphviz more than I should, but would it
be possible to straighten the arrows? I need the labels to be over the arrow, not to the side as with label/xlabel; I'm using boxes to hold what is essentially label text, since using labels on the edges seems to lead to whacky behavior when the labels are long.

```
digraph G {
    node [shape=rect style=filled
         fontcolor=white fontsize=12 fontname="Helvetica Bold"]
    edge [style=solid color="#777777"]

    // introduce nodes; set fill
    a1, a2, a3 [fillcolor="#438dd5"]
    c1         [fillcolor="#08427b"]

    b1, b2, b3 [fillcolor=white fontcolor=black fontname="Helvetica" shape=plain]

    a1 -> b1[dir=none]
    a2 -> b2[dir=none]
    a3 -> b3[dir=none]

    b1 -> c1
    b2 -> c1
    b3 -> c1

    { rankdir=LR  rank=same  a1 a2 a3  }
    { rankdir=LR  rank=same  b1 b2 b3 }
    { rankdir=LR  rank=same  c1 }
}
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350617/how-to-place-edge-labels-on-edge-in-graphviz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do it using [tables](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#html) with no borders and white background instead of labels. You would probably also need to use [`headlabel`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headlabel) or [`taillabel`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:taillabel), because in this case you can precisely control their position with [`labeldistance`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labeldistance) and [`labelangle`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:labelangle):

```
digraph G {
    node  [shape=rect style=filled
           fontcolor=white fontsize=12 fontname="Helvetica Bold"]
    graph [ranksep=1]
    edge  [style=solid color="#777777"]

    a1 [fillcolor="#438dd5"]
    a2 [fillcolor="#438dd5"]
    a3 [fillcolor="#438dd5"]
    c1 [fillcolor="#08427b"]

    a1 -> c1 [
        labeldistance=5
        labelangle=0
        headlabel=<
            <table bgcolor="white" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>b1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        >
    ]
    a2 -> c1 [
        labeldistance=4
        labelangle=0
        headlabel=<
            <table bgcolor="white" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>b2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        >
    ]
    a3 -> c1 [
        labeldistance=5
        labelangle=0
        headlabel=<
            <table bgcolor="white" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>b3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        >
    ]
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: thanks.. I'd tried tables, but I didn't know about the use of labelangle and labeldistance. Makes perfect sense... also liked the use of ranksep to move rows apart.

Comment: @RoyM ranksep affects the whole graph and you sometimes don't want it. In this case you could just add  'invisible' label to one of the edges. In this example you could `a2 -> c1 [label=" \n \n \n \n" ...`